# How to pass a List of objects from a controller to a view and access the properties of every objects?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have tried a lot of things but I can't figure out how to do it. I'm getting a List of objects from my database and  I actually want to display all the objects in a view.
So i get my list of objects thanks to that function:

```
List<Contact> ListeContacts = StructureData.DonneListeContact(NumDossier);
```

Then I pass my list to the ViewBag :

```
ViewBag.ListeContacts = ListeContacts;
```

So now I would like to display all the properties of each object in a select in the view, so I tried that way:

```
<select>
    @foreach (System.Data.DataRow Contact in ViewBag.ListeContact)
         {
           <option>@Html.DisplayName(Contact["nom_contact"].ToString())</option>
         }
</select>
```

But it shows me a "NullReferenceExeption" on the foreach. There are a lot of examples on the net but all are done with EntityFramework so it's simple when using a model data structure. Does somebody has an idea ?

Comment: Where is the `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: oh sorry, i edited the post

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
<select>
    @foreach (var contact in ViewBag.ListeContacts)
         {
           <option>@Html.DisplayName(contact["nom_contact"].ToString())</option>
         }
</select>
```

It looks like you have a `list of Contact` and you are trying to get a `DataRow` from the collection?

**EDIT**: Also make sure the property you are referencing exists, i.e. `nom_contact`

Comment: Yes I've just tried that:'<select>
                                            @foreach (extranetClient.Models.Classes.Contact Contact in ViewBag.ListeContact)
                                            {
                                                <option>@Html.DisplayName(Contact.Nom)</option>
                                            }
                                        </select>' but it still shows me the same error...

Comment: is **nom_contact** a property? Put a break on the line `ViewBag.ListeContacts = ListeContacts;` and check the values in **ListeContacts**

Comment: Yes exactly, it's the first property of the object Contact. OKay, will try right now

Comment: So 'ViewBag.ListeContacts' has 19 rows, so 19 Contact object. All the values are correct.

Comment: Like most of the time, it's just a matter of variable name syntax. IN the controller : 'ViewBag.ListeContacts' and in the view : 'ViewBag.ListeContact'. That way it won't work for sure.. I'm really sorry everyone, little bit tired. Thanks

Comment: Out of interest, try this code: `<ul>
@foreach (var contact in ViewBag.ListeContact)
{
    <li>
        @contact["nom_contact"].ToString()
    </li>
}
</ul>` Also, can you add the code for **Contact** class, since you posted code here with a different property **<option>@Html.DisplayName(Contact.Nom)</option>**

Comment: I have tried but it shows me a "binder exception". I found the solution: '<select>
                                            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.ListeContacts)
                                            {
                                                <option>@item.Nom</option>
                                            }
                                        </select>'

Comment: So, the property was wrong? **nom_contact** should have been **Nom**?

Comment: No, i just forget the s at the end of the name of the list : I wrote it like that in the view : ListeContact and in the controller ListeContacts. Sorry again.

Comment: That's why I use **strongly-typed** views :)  I have altered my answer to include the **s**, the other issue was the use of `DataRow` which was fixed using **var** or **Contact**

Answer (score 0):

You have assign to ViewBag.ListeContacts but take as ViewBag.ListeContact. You have miss the the letter "s" at the end of the variable name.

Then you can cast it back to List as bellow.

```
List<Contact> ListeContacts = (List<Contact>)ViewBag.ListeContacts
```